# I can't conect to Wifi internet after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless

I can't conect to Wifi internet after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 : Could you guide me step by step from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

13.10 is old and unsupported.

I would advise you to go hook it up to Ethernet and upgrade to the newest version Ubuntu 14.10, because there is better hardware compatibility.

And you wont have to bother installing a bunch of drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... This is actually quite a common problem when upgrading. Drivers usually get mixed up and thing don't work right. Can you tell me how many times you've upgraded your computer? The more it's upgraded, th more broken drivers there can be. 
Anyway, try going to: Settings -> Drivers (at the bottom) -> and find your Wi-Fi adapter driver. If it's not there, chances are it's corrupted or not installed. There are a lot of possibilities for that, so I'll try do dive into that in the meantime.
Cheers, Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks But I can't find "drivers" I have "additional drivers" that leads me to "softwares and updates" OR if I go to network I have "network proxy" . It is only the second time I upgrade my computer ( in 4 years). Should I upgrade for the 14.10 version? Thanks laetitia

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to resolve this issue is to plug in your ethernet cord (it looks like a telephone wire, but wider) into your router. But that would restrict you from moving away from the router. Otherwise, it would definitely be a better idea to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.01.2 LTS (for average users) or 14.10 (for more experienced users), because Ubuntu 13.10 is already pretty outdated and unsupported. Doing a fresh install will clear all your old and broken drivers from previous installs and start fresh. If you don't know how or just want to upgrade, it may require some more investigation involving searching through you system folders and installing drivers manually, which is not an easy task. Of course, it could be that your wireless adapter is broken from wear and tear, which is common in old computers. Can you tell me if you computer is a laptop or desktop, and how old it is (when it was bought)?

Comment: Hi, Finally I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 to another computer and I installed it on mine as I could not connect to wire internet either. It works fine. Thanks

Comment: I'm happy that it works!